# Best way to store AES keys (web api) while dealing with multi tenants (key per tenant)

Tags: encryption, web-application, key-management, .net

I have some data to encrypt on my database and every tenant will have his own database so surely every tenant will have a different key.

I'm searching for the best way to store the key for every tenant.

Web api written using c# .net and I'm planning on using the AESManaged class to encrypt/decrypt the needed data.

Comment: What do you mean by multiple tenants over here?

Comment: @Limit It's the concept that every client will have his own database, so every client will have a different key.

Comment: Why are the tenants not responsible for managing their own keys?

Comment: @Limit I offered the idea to my Project Manager and he didn't like it. Mostly going to store it in a different server (AWS or Azure)

Comment: Storing it on a different server is not really going to make it more secure IMO. Plus, if an attacker knows that you have this architecture, he is more likely to just go after the server and fetch all your keys.